# Guided Partitioning

Tags: partitioning

I read from some documentation that using Ubuntu's guided partitioning defaults will create a root partition and a swap partition. However, when I used that approach it actually created 5 partitions, and only the root partition looks familiar:

```
/dev/sdb5       227G   21G  194G  10% /
udev            1.5G  4.0K  1.5G   1% /dev
tmpfs           606M  844K  606M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            1.5G  152K  1.5G   1% /run/shm
```

what is udev, tmpfs, /run/lock/ and /run/shm?

What's even more interesting about this situation is that the guided partition didn't even allow me to select the partition to use. It just ended up using (wrongfully) my storage sdb drive rather than using my sda ext4 partition of my sda drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation that you have read is correct. Ubuntu by default will create 2 partitions. One is root (/) and the other is a separate partition for swap space.

Those that you are looking at the result of (I assume) `mount` command , are partitions inside root partition. This command `mount` is not showing a list of the created partitions but the mounted partitions at current time instead.

See `man mount` for more info and use the `sudo parted -l` to list your actual created partitions.

As for the mistake about the partitioning I will try to guess the situation you might faced ,because the info that you gave are incomplete.
Maybe If you had already 4 primary partitions (on MBR) you couldn't create more , because 4 is a limit of primary partitions on MBR.

What is MBR ? I will quote a "beautiful" short but comprehensive answer from ubuntuforums.org

> MBR or master boot record is what we have been using to boot PC's
>   since the introduction of the IBM pc. We have 4 partitions, but it was
>   modified to allow converting one to an extended partition so we could
>   add more logical partitions. It also has a maximum of 2TB and since
>   they are now selling 2TB drives the next generation of drives will not
>   use MBR.
>
> GPT is a newer partitioning scheme used by Apple and some Windows
>   servers. All the software you use must be GPT aware for it to work.
>   Grub legacy (some versions) was modified to at least be GPT aware. New
>   Grub2 is GPT aware.

[Source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1296348&p=8136501#post8136501)

Comment: hmmmmmm, so is there a command which tells you the partition the currently running ubuntu os is on?

Comment: actually silly me, its the df command. Thats the command I used for the output in the question, and the / root partition is the current partition which in this case was installed on the second drive sdb

Comment: ok so I installed ubuntu desktop again but this time I used the manual option rather than the guided option and I installed it on the second partion of sda ext4, and it successfully installed there. Now I want to wipe out anything on my second drive sdb, including the guided install that is there. If I wipe out everything on sdb, will grub remain on boot?

Comment: @JohnMerlino , the grub always installed at the MBR of the first hard drive (/dev/sda). In case you have changed the grub location manually, then you must be careful. In case you delete grub with the deletion of /dev/sdb contents , you can re-install grub from an Ubuntu Live CD/DVD or USB media. Also you can use [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and leave it to do this job for you automatically. So proceed. Do not afraid. If you make a mistake with grub , you can easily fix it.